# Scraping Menu Data from Weedmaps

Tags: python, jquery, html, css, web-scraping

I'm currently trying to find a way to scrape menu data from dispensaries on weedmaps.com. However, I haven't had much luck so far developing an intuition into how the site actually works in regards to where the data lies in order to scrape it.

There are really only 3 things I'd like to do. Get the names of each strain, get the quantities, and get the relevant prices for each quantity. However, when I take a look at the source code for the page, I can't find any particular lines that actually refer to the names, quantities, or prices shown on the menu.

I'd like to find the data listed here:
[Weedmaps Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTmbS.png)

Going through the page source code, though, there doesn't seem to be to me a clear way to find the code that displays that.

Here's the link for the source code (chrome):

view-source:https://weedmaps.com/deliveries/silicon-valley-farms#/menu

As I'm a novice when it comes to working with web-scripting languages, I would appreciate any help or advice that I can get with this matter. And if anyone has any suggestions, I'm literate in Python, and trying to learn javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Weedmaps returns data in json format. You can access the data by viewing the ajax request url in the network tab of Chrome Dev tools. Following is a link of a  tutorial for doing the same as above, but using a different website:
https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-scrape-store-locations-from-walmart-com-using-python-3/